# How to add a tab underneath your UINavigationItem?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

What I'm trying to do is something similar to say, the "Explore" tab that appears underneath the navigation item in Foursquare's iPhone app.

http://reviews.cnet.com/i/tim/2011/03/10/foursquare-iphone.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create UIToolBar for your view. For refer 
http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/11/how-to-make-a-toolbar-with-uitoolbar/

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work. Thanks! Any idea about what I would have to do to keep it locked in that position? As in, if I attach it to a table view, what do I have to do to keep it locked when I scroll through the table view cells?

Comment: You can try by adding the toolbar to tableHeaderView.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding a UIToolbar to your view